# What is the version of Elastic APM which is compatible with Django 1.6.11?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, elastic-apm

I am getting errors with ElasticAPM version 5.5.2 while running

```
python manage.py elasticapm check
```

Error: logging_config_func(self.LOGGING) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig dictConfigClass(config).configure() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 577, in configure '%r: %s' % (name, e)) ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'elasticapm': Cannot resolve 'elasticapm.contrib.django.handlers.LoggingHandler': No module named apps

Django: 1.6.11
Python: 2.7
ElastcAPM: 5.5.2

Comment: Please don't use Django 1.6! It is not supported anymore for a very long time (I think april **2015**), you can see the support range here: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ .

Comment: elastic-apm [1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/elastic-apm/1.0.0/) was released in December 2017 - Django 1.6 was already end of life by then. Even that version of elastic-apm tries to import `django.apps` [here](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/blob/v1.0.0/elasticapm/contrib/django/apps.py#L3), so it will require at least Django 1.7.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I cannot do anything here. In our orgainisation this is the prod setup and its surely not going to change for now. I need adjust here.

Comment: @Alasdair Let me know if there is any ray of hope.

Comment: @FarheenNilofer: well there are some known vulnerabilities (https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-10199/product_id-18211/version_id-165615/Djangoproject-Django-1.6.html). The LTS versions are constructed if one does not want to update often, but 1.6 is really (really!) not a good idea.

Comment: Your organisation could fork the library, and change the code so that it works with Django 1.6. I can't help you do that though.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, we are planning to do the same.